# Xcode Animated Tab Bar Controller - setting the appearance of icons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have Animated Tab Bar Controller:

[image]

I would like to change it so that it looks like this:

[image]

the change would concern:
- space between the icon and the inscription (vertical),
- the middle button should be in this circle, raised up.

Does anyone know how I could do it?
I can share my Storyboard file.

I'm using this component:
https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar

The project is in Swift 4.

Comment: reduce your image sizes to half of current size:)

Comment: not do this for central tab button

Comment: change they insets  of button for y coordinate to -30(required value).

Comment: so I have to upload a smaller file in xcode - assets? Is this parameter set somewhere in xcode?

Comment: yes exactly right now they are too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions

1) space between the icon and the inscription (vertical)

```
->> Reduce size of images
```

2)  the middle button should be in this circle, raised up.

```
->>> get bigger image of circle and apply image inset
```

Note: Make sure whatever you value you apply on other side it should be same value as negative like in image I have applied **2** on top and other side **-2** on bottom, If you don't do this you will get unexpected output on clicking

[image]

**BOUNS**

If you want your image as it is then apply Render as original

[image]

Hope it is helpful

Comment: I haven't this option :( I have only this: https://ibb.co/hC52Tc
https://ibb.co/iZZ7uH

Comment: @ŁukaszBetta Sorry didn't get you you not have this option ?, Click on tabbar item and on right panel you can see that all options available. and for last image go to image .assest  and select 1x image and on right panel you can see that options

Comment: Thank you. Button in a circle - is it a picture in the shape of a circle, or a picture with an added circle from the level of xcode?

Comment: @ŁukaszBetta Yes in image button is circle image with original render mode because i want image same as original don't want any tint for selected or non selected

Comment: @ŁukaszBetta What is issue you are facing now ?

Comment: I'm trying to make this raised button. After lifting the button on the top, the icon gets smaller

Comment: @ŁukaszBetta For center image you need larger icon like 65 by 65 for 1x